# Xcode crashes when attempting to create a file

Tags: xcode, crash

If I start up Xcode 10.3 on MacOS 10.14.6 and then try to create a new file (cmd-N), Xcode will crash. Actually trying to open *any* file will cause it to crash. The welcome window comes up as does all the other windows in the Windows menu. Preferences will open but opening the Fonts & Colors tab will cause Xcode to crash (all other tabs work fine.)

I have uninstalled everything including everything I could find in both my Library and the global Library and reinstalled from the App store but no luck.

I'm guessing it's some sort of font issue but I'm not sure. I'm looking for any ideas here.

Currently, I'm downloading Xcode 11 to see what happens with that.

Here is the beginning of the crash stack:

```
Process:               Xcode [698]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            Xcode
Version:               10.3 (14492.2)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       832020435
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [698]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-09-15 21:15:38.288 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G95)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        8D9EF665-0B80-ADDC-F96B-EF8B48AFF1D2


Time Awake Since Boot: 1100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending newDocument: to <IDEApplicationCommands: 0x7fb35664e4f0> from <NSMenuItem: 0x7fb359ce6260 File…>
ProductBuildVersion: 10G8
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: The view controller: "IDEConsoleArea" is loading the nib file: "IDEConsoleArea".
  1: Replacement view is installing: <IDEConsoleArea: 0x7fb3596088e0 representing: <DVTExtension 0x7fb359384760: Default Console (Xcode.IDEKit.Console.DefaultConsole) v0.1 from com.apple.dt.IDEKit>>
  2: Replacement view is installing: <IDEEditorArea: 0x7fb35b2e6550 representing: (null)>
  3: Sending newDocument: to <IDEApplicationCommands: 0x7fb35664e4f0> from <NSMenuItem: 0x7fb359ce6260 File…>
```

Comment: Installing Xcode 11 GM seed worked and fixed my Xcode 10.3 app as well. I still don't know why 10.3 wasn't working, but at least it's working now.